# Is it possible to generate knex seed files from a database dump?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, migration, knex.js

In my case, I am using mysql. However, I am looking for a general solution for generating knex seed files from either the currently running database or a database dump.

I could do [something like](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/944#issuecomment-244346847):

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
    var sql = fs.readFileSync('./data/workbench.sql').toString();
    return knex.raw('DROP DATABASE workbench')
       .then(() => knex.raw('CREATE DATABASE workbench'))
       .then(() => knex.raw(sql))
};
```

but it's not ideal ...

Comment: I would be surprised if  `knex.raw(sql)` wouldn't cause problems in some cases. Anyways if it really works (with also bigger dumps) I suppose its fine too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `node-postgresql` driver doesn't support passing multiple statements in one string.

I'm calling shell command (with shelljs) when I need to restore dump from file from node code.

Comment: If you add `{ multipleStatements: true }` in the connection-object you pass the the Knex instance it will allow multipleStatements and not throw the parse error.

Comment: Yeah, with mysql it should be fine. When I wrote the answer, I somehow missed the `mysql` tag.